# Why is Javascript loading only once?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Please refer to the following SCRIPT

```
<html>
  <style>
     #div_content {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: yellow;
        position: relative;
     }
     #btn_addContent{
       position: absolute;
       left: 0;
       bottom: 0;
     }
    #btn_removeContent{
       position: absolute;
       right: 0;
       bottom: 0;
     }
  </style>

  <body>
     <div id="div_content">
       <p> Existing Content </p>
       <button id="btn_addContent">Add Content </button>
       <button id="btn_removeContent">Remove Content </button>
     </div>
     
  </body>

  <script>
      var divElement = document.getElementById("div_content");

      function addContent(){
         divElement.innerHTML = divElement.innerHTML + "<P> New Content </p>";
      }

      function removeContent(){
         divElement.parentNode.removeChild(divElement);
      }


      var btnAddContent= document.getElementById("btn_addContent");
      btnAddContent.onclick = addContent;

      var btnRemoveContent = document.getElementById("btn_removeContent");
      btnRemoveContent.onclick = removeContent;
      
  </script>

</html>
```

While running this script, any of the function is running  that too only once means Javascript is loading only once kindly do the needful.
i.e., if I want to `addcontent` I am able to add it single time
and at the same time means on the same page if at all I want to remove the `div_content` section I am not able to do so,
but, on fresh reload I'm able to remove the `div_content` section
that is for every reload I can only do add or remove not both and not even multiple adding.

Comment: Your HTML is totally invalid. `html` can only have `head` and `body` as children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`innerHTML +=` will destroy all the child elements reference(*Remove and add again in DOM tree*).

> Use [**`.appendChild`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

*From [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)*, `innerHTML` removes all of element's `children`, parses the content string and assigns the resulting nodes as `children` of the `element`.

```js
var divElement = document.getElementById("div_content");

function addContent() {
  var elem = document.createElement('p');
  elem.textContent = 'New Content';
  divElement.appendChild(elem);
}

function removeContent() {
  divElement.parentNode.removeChild(divElement);
}
var btnAddContent = document.getElementById("btn_addContent");
btnAddContent.onclick = addContent;
var btnRemoveContent = document.getElementById("btn_removeContent");
btnRemoveContent.onclick = removeContent;
```

```css
#div_content {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}
#btn_addContent {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
#btn_removeContent {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_content">
  <p>Existing Content</p>
  <button id="btn_addContent">Add Content</button>
  <button id="btn_removeContent">Remove Content</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It Worked.. Thank You.. Rayon.. :-)

Comment: @PavaniAkula, I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_